# Using a GList datatype in python function via SWIG

Tags: python, c, swig, glib

I'm create a python script which calls some C functions via SWIG.

I haven't had a problem calling most functions, but one particular function takes a GList datatype as an argument:

The C function is defined along the along the lines of:

```
void some_function(GList *guid_list)
```

I'm trying to call it via it's SWIG created python module along the lines of

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
module_from_swig.some_function(some_list)
```

But getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/module_from_swig.py", line 1828, in some_function
    return _module_from_swig.some_function(*args)

TypeError: in method 'some_function', argument 1 of type 'GList *'
```

I'm assuming I need to convert the python list into a Glist somehow, but not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: @xaxxon - I've edited my question to inclide the in the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your SWIG interface file needs the definition of `GList`, then you *may* be able to get away with a minimal SWIG file like:

```
%module MyModule

%inline %{
#include "Glist.h"
#include "functions.h"
%}
```

And use the function like:

```
>>> import MyModule
>>> glist = MyModule.GList()
>>> glist.some_field = some_value
>>> glist.some_other_field = some_value
>>> MyModule.some_function(glist)
```

This is pretty vague but not a lot to go on.  If `GList` is complicated a `typemap` may need to be written.  Provide a simple example of the function and header files along with the SWIG .i file you are using (ideally, that compiles and demonstrates the problem) and you'll get better feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help - this is much clearer now. I already have a SWIG .i file so will try making the changes you suggest and see what happens.